# A question about uniform convergence of $g_n=f\left(\frac xn\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you give me some hint how to prove this statement:

Suppose $f(x)$ is some function on R.
Prove: If $g_n=f\left(\frac xn\right)$ converges uniformly to zero on R than $f(x)=0$ for all x.

I simply does not understand how to conclude from $sup\left|f\left(\frac xn\right)\right|<\epsilon$ that $f(x)=0$ for all x.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0\in \Bbb R$ then we have

$$\mu_n:=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\left|f\left(\frac xn\right)\right|\ge \left|f\left(\frac {x_0n}n\right)\right|=|f(x_0)|\ge0$$
and by the uniform convergence we have $$\mu_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
so by the squeeze theorem we see that $f(x_0)=0$. Conclude.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\left|f\left(\frac xn\right)\right|\ge \left|f\left(\frac {x_0n}n\right)\right|$ ?

Comment: $x_0 n \in \mathbb{R}$ so the definition of the sup gives us this

Answer (score 0):

For $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|f(x/n)| < \varepsilon$ for all(!!) $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $n \geq n_0$. What does this mean?